# Get access to specific data from Google Analytics API

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm developing a site where customers authorize my app to access their site's information Google Analytic API. I want only limited information from their accounts.

1. Unique Vistits
2. Total Visits

Is there any way to request access only to these information rather than getting access to all other info.

My main concern is if there are security breach another party can gain access to these google accounts and get the information about other sites.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything? Show us your code please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lowest level [scope](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/gdataAuthorization#OAuth2Authorizing) you can grant an application is readonly.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly
```

Which will give access to all populated [dimensions and metrics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets). Most people limit sensitive information by limiting what data is populated in what views.